# Cannot install Django 2 Beta 1 on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip, beta

I'm trying to install Django 2 beta 1 on an Ubuntu Server 16.04 using the command line shown on Django's download page without success.

The given command line is: `pip install --pre django` but when I run it, it is trying to install Django 1.11.6. (`Downloading Django-1.11.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)`)

Does anyone know how I can successfully install the beta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: I uninstalled every version of Python I had (2.7, 3.5, 3.6) as well as Pip.

Then installed only Python 3.5 and installed Pip via a python script retrieved by Curl (had to do this way otherwise apt was installing Python 2.7 along with Pip) with these commands:

```
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python3 get-pip.py
```

Finally, I installed the Django 2 beta1 with the original command:

```
pip install --pre Django
```

Answer (score 2):

Write explicit the version of Django you want to install:

```
pip install --pre Django==2.0b1
```

The option `--pre` (prerelease) can be also left out.

EDIT (after comment):

This definitely works as I have tried it. To list all versions of a package I use a dirty solution like:

```
pip install django==0
```

As `pip` can't find this nonexisting version it returns a list with all available versions `(from versions: ...)`. The last version there is `2.0b1`.

EDIT:

I strongly assume you're using Python 2. That would explain why the installation fails. If you want to try out Django 2, you'll need Python 3.
This is what the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/) says:

> Django 2.0 supports Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. We **highly recommend** and
>   only officially support the latest release of each series.

Using virtual environments installing Django 2.0 could look like this:

1. Install `virtualenv` (check this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Python/Virtualenv)).
2. Create new virtual environment called *djangobeta* with python3. Execute the following command in the shell:

   `virtualenv -p python3 djangobeta`
3. Install Django 2.0 beta 1:

   `pip install --pre django`

Comment: Pip can't find this version and is returning the following error: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.0b1 (from versions: [...])
No matching distribution found for Django==2.0b1"

Comment: Check the last entry in `(from versions: [..])`. It must be `2.0b1`.

Comment: nope, surprisingly the last entry is 1.11.6, see the pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/JuujK6dd

Comment: That's very peculiar and gives a hint why `pip install --pre django` installs 1.11.6. Which versions of `pip` and `python` do you use?

Comment: Indeed ! I have pip-9.0.1 and python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 installed

Comment: Do you use virtual environments? If yes, then create one using python 3.5 or 3.6 and you can install Django 2.0b1.

Comment: There's an issue here: When I install pip, it is also installing python 2.7 and when I remove python 2.7 it removes pip and I cannot install Django 2b1. Thus, Python 3.5 and 3.6 are also present and installed on the server