# install Django 2.0.2 Could not find a version

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip

Im trying to use  `pip install Django==2.0.2` but throw ,

`No matching distribution found for Django==2.0.2` , 
and it´s weird cause im using the same command from [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/), 
what can i do ?

Im using OSX, and install `virtual env` without call explicit python3.

Comment: `pip3 install django`

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar is telling you that Django 2.0 dropped support for Python 2.7 so if your default `pip` is linked to Python 2.7 (as the default for many linux distros) you will not be able to install this version unless you use pip3.

Comment: Or preferably, `virtualenv env -p python3`, activate it and `pip install django`

Comment: same result but , i remember create the virtual env with  `virtualenv env` without calling python3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install Django 2 Beta 1 on Ubuntu Server 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929519/cannot-install-django-2-beta-1-on-ubuntu-server-16-04)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First i  created a new virtual env with  `virtualenv env -p python3`
then,  run  the  command : `pip install django` to install django 2.
But if you create your virtual env with this line `virtualenv my_project` in your terminal, 
you need to explicit call pip3  :   `pip3 install django`