# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for django

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv

I was able to install django once in a virtual enviroment. Now whenever i try to install it with

```
pip install django==2.07
```

it returns:

```
 Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))': /simple/django/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==2.0.7 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django==2.0.7
```

Also I have:
pip- 10.0.1
virtualenv- 16.0.0

This is killing me. I believe it has something to do with pip. I am a beginner so walk me through. Thanks!

Comment: Check that you don't have a firewall or something that is blocking pip from accessing the internet?

Comment: You may like to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622272/install-django-2-0-2-could-not-find-a-version

Comment: Can you show the output of `env |grep -i proxy`? I think you have your proxy set to something that is not accepting connections.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ProxyError+Cannot+connect+to+proxy

Comment: my firewall is turned off.

Comment: i got it fixed. i either had to turn off my proxy or use --proxy and add username/pass which only worked about half the time( ? ). thanks everyone

Answer (score 16):

Django above 2 version support only python3 , so try

```
pip3 install django==2.0.7
```

if you have python3.5 and above in your system

Also to see supported versions by pip try:

```
pip install django==0
```

and

```
pip3 install django==0
```

Comment: i still get the same error. I tried pip and pip3 and also tried installing other packages and the same error keeps popping up. Any other ideas?

Comment: pip3 did it for me (python3.7)

Comment: I know this is old. But if anyone has the same problem, make sure you are not using vpn.

Comment: I was using a virtual environment with python 2. Had to recreate it using python 3.